# Android Tabhost widget in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm trying to figure out all this Android UI stuff, and when doing the [Hello Tabwidget](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html) tutorial in Eclipse, I'm not getting the TabHost to show up properly.  Have I not installed all the required software or not configured Eclipse correctly?  The graphical layout for the main.xml copied from the tutorial looks like this:

[image: tabhost error]

I just want to get the tabs working.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you talking about not seeing the tabs in the visual designer in eclipse? This is a known issue.

Comment: Oh, it is?  I couldn't even find it in the list of widgets.  Is that also normal?

Comment: Perhaps. If you check my link below, you will see that it should be fixed for Honeycomb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the following bug report: [Android Issue 13092](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=13092)